# Compiling a C++ to smallest possible size

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-optimization, filesize

I am curious about how I should go about compiling a relatively simple C++ script to its smallest possible executable size.

Without going too much into *why* this program will be useful, here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long inputAdjust(const string myinput) {
    unsigned long long myadjust;
    if (myinput=="B") {
        myadjust=1;
    } else if (myinput=="K") {
        myadjust=1024;
    } else if (myinput=="M") {
        myadjust=1048576;
    } else if (myinput=="G") {
        myadjust=1073741824;
    } else {
        myadjust=1;
    }
    return myadjust;
}

long long asmAnswer (const string myinput, const unsigned long long fir, const unsigned long long sec) {
    unsigned long long myanswer;
    if (myinput=="A") {
        myanswer = fir + sec;
    } else if (myinput=="S") {
        myanswer = fir - sec;
    } else if (myinput=="M") {
        myanswer = fir * sec;
    } else {
        myanswer = fir + sec;
    }
    return myanswer;
}

double dAnswer (const unsigned long long fir, const unsigned long long sec) {
    double myanswer;
    myanswer = (double)fir/sec;
    return myanswer;
}

void outputAnswer (const string myinput, const long long myanswer) {
    if (myinput=="B") {
        printf("%lld",myanswer);
    } else if (myinput=="K") {
        printf("%.2f",(double)(myanswer/1024));
    } else if (myinput=="M") {
        printf("%.2f",(double)(myanswer/1048576));
    } else if (myinput=="G") {
        printf("%.2f",(double)(myanswer/1073741824));
    } else if (myinput=="O") {
        if (myanswer>0) {
            if (myanswer<1024 && myanswer>-1024) {
                printf("%lld b",myanswer);
            } else if (myanswer<1048576 && myanswer>-1048576) {
                printf("%.2f kb",(double)(myanswer/1024));
            } else if (myanswer<1073741824 && myanswer>-1073741824) {
                printf("%.2f mb",(double)(myanswer/1048576));
            } else {
                printf("%.2f gb",(double)(myanswer/1073741824));
            }
        }
    } else { //assume bytes
        printf("%lld",myanswer);
    }
}

void outputAnswer (const string myinput, const double myanswer) {
    if (myinput=="P") {
        printf("%.3f",(myanswer*100.0));
    } else {
        printf("%.3f",myanswer);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    if (argc < 5) {
        // If we have less than 5 arguments, output the usage 
        string filename = argv[0];
        printf("\nUsage: bytemath.exe BKMG BKMGO[P] ASMD FirstNum SecondNum\n    First <OPERATOR> Second\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        string input =  argv[1];
        string output = argv[2];
        string oper =   argv[3];
        unsigned long long first =  atoll(argv[4]);
        unsigned long long second = atoll(argv[5]);
        unsigned long i_adjust;
        unsigned long o_adjust;

        i_adjust = inputAdjust(input);
        first *= i_adjust;
        second*= i_adjust;

        if (oper=="D") { // we want to divide so need to use a double rather than long
            double answer;
            answer = dAnswer(first, second);
            outputAnswer(output, answer);
        } else { // otherwise do +, -, or *
            long long answer;
            answer = asmAnswer(oper, first, second);
            outputAnswer(output, answer);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Basically it does math operations on large numbers because batch files can only work with 32-bit unsigned integers.  I could probably just use something like VBS but this is the solution I'm working with at the moment.

I need the program to be standalone, so it has to statically link to libraries.  I was able to get the size down from ~570kb to ~148kb by replacing all the `cout` commands with `printf`, but I'm wondering what else I can do to get the file size down.

I am compiling this with MiniGW 4.6, and this is my compile command at the moment:

`g++ -Os -s -static bytemath.cpp -o bytemath.exe`

Anything else I can do to reduce the file size without too much code rewriting?

Thanks.

*EDIT*

The two big savers were getting rid of `<iostream>` and `<string>`, which I was able to do by replacing all my `cout` commands with `printf` and replacing my string comparisons with a char* comparison.  For the chars, I needed to make sure to access the 0th element of the array and compare it to a char in single quotes rather than double quotes (i.e. `if (myinput[0]=='P') {` rather than `if (myinput=="P") {`).

Thanks again everyone! 570kb to 18kb, works for me!

Comment: You really don't need all the printf call you have. Use your if statements to compute the values you want to out put then at the end output with one printf.

Comment: I did it that way since sometimes I'm outputting a `long long` and sometimes I'm outputting a `float`.  It has been a while since I've used c++, but to me this was easier.  Using a tip below to replace all the instances of `string` with `char*` worked, but I'd imagine this would help too, but the time it would take to fix that wouldn't result in that much space savings for this project (now that it is down to 18kb).  

Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but: remove the strings and replace them by enums and/or char*. You mostly use those strings like enums anyways and a simple if on the input chars can get you the enums.

Comment: Ah I could do that.  However, I'm not familial with enums.  It is true that all I'm using the strings for is comparisons in `if` statements, and I'm only ever looking at 1 character.  This tool is only going to be used by me for a very specific purpose, so I don't need a lot of error checking and things like that when inputing the arguments.

I'll play around with just regular char* and see if I can make the comparisons that way.

Comment: Yep, not sure if I could have done a straight Find and Replace, but I think I just replaced every instance of `string` with `char*` and got rid of `#include <string>` and that reduced it down to 18kb.  Good enough for me!  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ahhh nevermind, the program doesn't work now.  I don't think I can do `if (myinput=="A")` if the type of myinput is `char*`.  OK, I'll need to figure out how to do the comparisons.  I'm on the right track though, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits, OK, I think we are all good now.  In the if statements, I need to do `myinput[0]=='P'` since all I care about is the first letter of the argument anyways.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you have finished debugging, you can add '-s' to your compiler command.
'-s' means strip all symbols.
To strip  or modifies the symbol table attached to the output of the assembler and link editor can save space after a program has been debugged, and it will also limit dynamically bound symbols

In addition, try to pass std::string by ref instead of by value
change
      `inputAdjust(const string myinput)`
  to 
     `inputAdjust(const string& myinput)`
This may not help reduce binary size, but it will avoid heap allocation at runtime.

Comment: It has been a long time since I've done anything with C++, but I don't think I'm doing any debugging.  I'm just compiling this .cpp file with the g++ command I included in my comment.  Is there something I should run first (like making a .a file?)  and then run the compiler?

Comment: You already have `-s` in your compile command (assuming that does the same for mingw).